# Select all files with glob, except for specific file

Tags: bash, file, glob

I'm trying to match a glob that's *all* `.exe`'s in a nested folder, but skip over `UnityCrashHandler32.exe`/`UnityCrashHandler64.exe` explicitly.

I've been playing around with some combination of `!(UnityCrashHandler32\.exe|UnityCrashHandler64\.exe)` but it's not lining up correctly! Can't quite see what I'm missing

Thanks so much,
Ollie

Current Glob:

```
foo/{*/*,*}.exe
```

What I'd like it to do:

```
❌ foo/test.png
✅ foo/thing.exe
✅ foo/thing/thing.exe
❌ foo/UnityCrashHandler64.exe
❌ foo/UnityCrashHandler32.exe
❌ foo/thing/UnityCrashHandler64.exe
❌ foo/thing/UnityCrashHandler32.exe
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=foo%2F%7B%2A%2F%2A%2C%2A%7D.exe&matches=false&tests=foo%2Ftest.png&tests=foo%2Fthing.exe&tests=foo%2Fthing%2Fthing.exe&tests=foo%2FUnityCrashHandler64.exe&tests=foo%2FUnityCrashHandler32.exe&tests=foo%2Fthing%2FUnityCrashHandler64.exe&tests=foo%2Fthing%2FUnityCrashHandler32.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe?

```
foo/**/@(!(UnityCrashHandler[0-9][0-9])).exe
```

---

Or

```
foo/**/!(UnityCrashHandler[0-9][0-9]).exe
```

---

With more pattern/glob to match, put the `.exe` inside the last `)`

```
foo/**/@(!(UnityCrashHandler[0-9][0-9]).exe)
```

---

Add a pipe `|` after the `.exe` and add your next pattern/glob.

---

See

- [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)
- [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: That absolutely works! Thank you so much! - Need to readup on `@` - thanks

Comment: The `**` is `globstar` which is recursive, the rest is `extglob`